# How to use group by in contentresolver above android 4.0?

Tags: android, group-by, android-contentresolver

I want to query calllogs above android4.0 using group by,but it didn't work. It was the error:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "GROUP": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, number, date, duration, type, name, numbertype, numberlabel FROM logs WHERE (logs.logtype=100 OR logs.logtype=110 OR logs.logtype=900 OR logs.logtype=500 OR logs.logtype=800 OR logs.logtype=120 OR logs.logtype=510 OR logs.logtype=1000 OR (logs.logtype=200 AND number NOT IN (SELECT number FROM logs WHERE number LIKE '%@%')) OR logs.logtype=300 OR logs.logtype=950) AND (((0==0) GROUP BY (number),(type),(date/86400000) AND ((type != 4)) AND (logtype=100 OR logtype=500 OR logtype=950))) ORDER BY date DESC.

What should I do?